# doc2vec: Pull documents from inferred document

Tags: doc2vec

i am new in word/paragraph embedding and trying to understand via doc2vec in GENSIM. I would like to seek advice on whether my understanding is incorrect. My understanding is that doc2vec is potentially able to return documents that may have semantically similar content. As a test, i tried the following and have the following questions.

**Question 1**: I noted that every run of training with the exact same parameters and examples will result in a model that produces very different results from previous trains (E.g. Different vectors and different ranking of similar documents eveytime).. Why is this so indeterministic? As such, can this be reliably used for any practical work?

**Question 2**: Why am i not getting the tag ids of the top similar documents instead? 
    Results: [('day',0.477),('2016',0.386)....

**Question 2 answer**: The problem was due to model.most_similar, should use model.docvecs.most_similar instead

Please advise if i misunderstood anything?

**Data prep**

I had created multiple documents with a sentence each. I had deliberately made it such that they are distinctly different semantically.

A: It is a fine summer weather, with the birds singing and sun shining bright.

B: It is a lovely day indeed, if only i had a degree in appreciating.

C: 2016-2017 Degree in Earth Science Earthly University

D: 2009-2010 Dip in Life and Nature Life College

Query: Degree in Philosophy from Thinking University from 2009 to 2010

**Training**

I trained the documents (tokens as words, running index as tag)

```
tdlist=[]
docstring=['It is a fine summer weather, with the birds singing and sun shining bright.',
           'It is a lovely day indeed, if only i had a degree in appreciating.',
           '2016-2017 Degree in Earth Science Earthly University',
           '2009-2010 Dip in Life and Nature Life College']
counter=1
for para in docstring:
   tokens=tokenize(para) #This will also strip punctuation 
   td=TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.to_unicode(str.encode(' '.join(tokens))).split(), str(counter))
   tdlist.append(td)
   counter=counter+1

model=gensim.models.Doc2Vec(tdlist,dm=0,alpha=0.025, size=20, min_alpha=0.025, min_count=0)
for epoch in range(200):
    model.train(tdlist, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
```

**Inference**

I then attempted to infer the query. Although they are many missing words in the vocab for the query, i would expect closest document similarity results for C and D. But the results only gave me a list of 'words' followed by a similarity score. I am unsure if my understanding is wrong. Below is my code extract.

```
mydocvector=model.infer_vector(['Degree' ,'in' ,'Philosophy' ,'from' ,'Thinking' ,'University', 'from', '2009', 'to', '2010'])
print(model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[mydocvector])
```

Comment: It seems you've made a mistake during training, considering each word as a separate document, rather than taking the entire sentence as 1 unit. Your code for inference is correct, but without more details it's hard to pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: Hi, i've updated the post to reflect the portion where i create the document. It is a list of token in unicode as required by doc2vec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc2Vec doesn't work well on toy-sized datasets - few documents, few total words, few words per document. You'll absolutely want more documents than vector dimensions (`size`), and ideally tens-of-thousands of documents or more.

The second argument to `TaggedDocument` should be a *list* of tags. By supplying a single string-of-an-int, each of its elements (characters) will be seen as tags. (With just documents `1` to `4` this won't yet hurt, but as soon as you have document `10`, Doc2Vec will see it as tags `1` and `0`, unless you supply it as `['10']` (a single-element list).

Yes, to find most-similar documents you use `model.docvecs.most_similar()` rather than `model.most_similar()` (which only operates on learned words, if any).

You are using `dm=0` mode, which is a pretty good starting idea – it's fast and often a top-performer. But note that this mode *doesn't* train word-vectors too. So anything you ask for from the top model, like `model['summer']` or `model.most_similar('sun')`, will be nonsense results based on randomly-initialized but never-trained words. (If you need words trained too, either add `dbow_words=1` to the `dm=0` mode, or use a `dm=1` mode. But for pure doc-vectors, `dm=0` is a pretty good choice.)

There's no need to call `train()` in a loop - or indeed at all, given the line above it. The form you've used to instantiate `Doc2Vec`, with an actual corpus `tdlist` as the first argument, already triggers model-setup *and* training, using the default number of `iter` passes (5) and the supplied `alpha` and `min_alpha`. Now, for Doc2Vec training you often want more passes (10 to 20 are common, though smaller datasets might benefit from even more). And for any training, for properly gradient-descent, you want the effective learning-rate `alpha` to gradually decline to a negligible value, such as the default `0.0001` (rather than a forced same-as-starting value).

The only situation where you'd usually call `train()` explicitly is if you instantiate the model *without* a corpus. In that case, you'd need to both call `model.build_vocab(tdlist)` (to let the model initialize with a discovered vocabulary), and then some form of `train()` - but you'd still need only one call to train, supplying the desired number of passes. (Allowing the default `model.iter` 5 passes, inside an outer loop of 200 iterations, means a total of 1000 passes over the data... and all at the same fixed `alpha`, which is not proper gradient-descent.)

When you have a beefier dataset, you may find results improve with a higher `min_count`. Usually words that appear only a few times can't contribute much meaning, and thus only serve as noise slowing training and interfering with other vectors becoming more expressive. (Don't assume "more words must equal better results".) Throwing out the singletons, or more, usually helps.

Regarding inference, almost none of the words in your inference text are in the training set. (I only see 'Degree', 'in', and 'University' repeated.) So in addition to all the issues above, inferring a good vector for the example text would be hard. With a richer training set, you'd likely get better results. It also often helps to increase the `steps` optional parameter to `infer_vector()` far above its default of 5.

Comment: Hi @gojomo. Thank you for your detailed explanation. I have a much better understanding now.